# Find and replace values in colum in File A, based on Find/Replace criteria in FileB

Tags: awk, replace, find

I have two files. the first is FileA, it consists of three colums (tab-delimited), see content below

FileA

```
House1   dog    blue
House2   cat    yellow
House3   bird   red
House4   cow   orange
House5   duck   black 
House6   cow    brown
```

The second is FileB, contains a two colunms (tab-delimited) FileB Column 1 contains a list of all unnique values in FileA column 2. FileB column 2 contains a list of values that I want their corresponding value in Colum 1 to be replaced by in FileA

FileB

```
dog     1
cat     2
cow     3
duck    4
bird    5
```

In other words I wish to find all of the values in FileA column 2 that match with FileB column 1 and replace them with their corresponding value in File B Column 2, and output the new FileA  to a new file ("FileA2")

The output for the new FileA (FileA2) should look like this (i.e names column 2 have all been changed to numbers, with each change corresponding to find-replace criteria in FileB)

```
House1   1  blue
House2   2  yellow
House3   5   red
House4   3  orange
House5   4   black 
House6   3   brown
```

Are there any awk, grep or sed one-liners that would do this?

Note: in real life my "FileA" has over 800,000 lines and over 4000 unique values in in colum 2, so doing it via my Linux terminal would be preferable.

Also, for future reference, are there any one-liners to extract a list of unique values from a single column in a given file?

Thank you in advance for your kind assistance.

Comment: You'll find few are going to write any code for you. This site works best when you come with a question and some code that illustrates the question. You are encouraged to do some research about how you might transform this data using whatever tool is most suitable for you. See [ask].

Comment: which language?

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick (`bash`) :

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

join -t $'\t' \
    <(sort -t $'\t' -k 2 FileA) \
    <(sort -t $'\t' -k 1 FileB) \
    -1 2 \
    -2 1 | \
sort -t $'\t' -k 2 | \
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" } {print $2, $4, $3}'
```

### Explanations

First, files need to be sorted to use `join` command :

```sh
sort -t $'\t' -k 2 FileA
sort -t $'\t' -k 1 FileB
```

Here, we are sorting `FileA` according to the 2nd column (`-k 2`) and `FileB` according to the 1st column (`-k 1`). Tab is used for both files as separators (`-t $'\t'`).

*Note* : Sorting the inputs could be done in a preparation step (storing sorted results in temporary files) to avoid re-sorting the files each time the whole command is executed).

Next, the `join` command takes as parameters :

- the separator (`-t $'\t'`)
- the sorted inputs (using `<(sort ...)`)
- the columns used for joining :

  - `-1 2` = 1st file, 2nd column
  - `-2 1` = 2nd file, 1st column

Once joined, and to get the output you need (sorted against the 2nd column of the input, the one containing `House`), we need to sort the output of the previous command by running `sort -t $'\t' -k 2`.

Finally, `awk` is used to get only needed columns (2nd column, 4th column and 3rd column, in that order), separated by `\t` (`BEGIN { OFS="\t" }`).

### Test

This command is tested on Linux host. You can test this command in same environment with Docker; in your current directory, you must have `FileA`, `FileB` and `join.sh`, an executable script containing the first command.

Running :

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/tmp -w /tmp debian:buster ./join.sh
```

returns :

```
House1  1       blue
House2  2       yellow
House3  5       red
House4  3       orange
House5  4       black
House6  3       brown
```

Comment: Hi norbjd thanks very much for your answer and your explanation. I have tried it but nothing seems to happen. I have since clarified my question, I realize now that some of it might have been unclear, sorry about that.

Comment: @user10234826 Just checked the command, it works on my host (Linux) with the files you provided (`FileA` and `FileB`). Maybe you have BSD command line tools on your hosts (like on MacOS) instead of GNU tools (Linux)? I'm thinking of this because I've already expected similar issues (bash script working on Linux but not on MacOS). Anyway, I have edited my answer and gave you an example (thanks to Docker) to show you it works on Linux hosts. Can you try to run the command bit by bit (first `join`, then `sort`, then `awk`) to see which part of the command is failing on your machine?